# Validation failed for query for method public abstract long com.rajesh.repository.CreditDebitRepository.fingById(long)

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jsp

I have a 3 table Credit is parent table Debit is child table and credit_debit is reference table given relation one to many. i want to get record based on cid

I have write query for getting that record from that two table but some error is display in console regarding hibernate Query. any one can help me how to write query for get record by id from two table in third table all two table id is stored.

1.Credit.java

```
package com.rajesh.model;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@Entity
@Table(name="credit")
public class Credit extends BaseEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private long cid;
    @Column @Order
    private long openingbalance;
    @Column
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date date;
    @Column @Order
    private long debittotal;
    @Column @Order
    private long drawertotal;
    @Column @Order
    private long debittotalplusdrawertotal;
    @Column @Order
    private long todaybusiness;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="credit_debit", 
               joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="c_id"), 
               inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="d_id"))
    private List<Debit> debits = new ArrayList<Debit>(Arrays.asList());
    public Credit() {

    }
    public Credit(long cid, long openingbalance, Date date, long debittotal, long drawertotal,
            long debittotalplusdrawertotal, long todaybusiness, List<Debit> debits) {
        super();
        this.cid = cid;
        this.openingbalance = openingbalance;
        this.date = date;
        this.debittotal = debittotal;
        this.drawertotal = drawertotal;
        this.debittotalplusdrawertotal = debittotalplusdrawertotal;
        this.todaybusiness = todaybusiness;
        this.debits = debits;
    }
    public long getCid() {
        return cid;
    }
    public void setCid(long cid) {
        this.cid = cid;
    }
    public long getOpeningbalance() {
        return openingbalance;
    }
    public void setOpeningbalance(long openingbalance) {
        this.openingbalance = openingbalance;
    }   
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public long getDebittotal() {
        return debittotal;
    }
    public void setDebittotal(long debittotal) {
        this.debittotal = debittotal;
    }
    public long getDrawertotal() {
        return drawertotal;
    }
    public void setDrawertotal(long drawertotal) {
        this.drawertotal = drawertotal;
    }
    public long getDebittotalplusdrawertotal() {
        return debittotalplusdrawertotal;
    }
    public void setDebittotalplusdrawertotal(long debittotalplusdrawertotal) {
        this.debittotalplusdrawertotal = debittotalplusdrawertotal;
    }
    public long getTodaybusiness() {
        return todaybusiness;
    }
    public void setTodaybusiness(long todaybusiness) {
        this.todaybusiness = todaybusiness;
    }
    public List<Debit> getDebit() { 
        return debits;
    }   
    public void setDebit(List<Debit> debits) {  
        this.debits = debits;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return "Credit [cid=" + cid + ", openingbalance =" + openingbalance + ", date=" + date + ", debittotal= " + debittotal + ", debittotalplusdrawertotal=" + debittotalplusdrawertotal + ", todaybusiness=" + todaybusiness + "]";
    }
}
```

2.Debit.java

```
package com.rajesh.model;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="debit")
public class Debit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private long did;
    @Column
    private String amount;
    @Column
    private String description; 

    public long getDid() {
        return did;
    }
    public void setDid(long did) {
        this.did = did;
    }
    public Debit() {

    }
    public Debit(String amount, String description) {
        super();
        this.amount = amount;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return "Debit [did=" + did + ", amount =" + amount + ", description=" + description + "]";
    }
}
```

3.CreditDebitRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface CreditDebitRepository extends  JpaRepository<Credit, Long>{

    @Query(value= "from Credit c join credit_debit cd on(c.cid=cd.c_id) join Debit d on(cd.d_id=d.did) WHERE c.cid=:cid")
    long fingById(long cid);
}
```

4.CreditDebitService.java

```
package com.rajesh.service;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.rajesh.model.Credit;
import com.rajesh.repository.CreditDebitRepository;

@Service
public class CreditDebitService {
    @Autowired
    CreditDebitRepository creditDebitRepository;

    public void save(Credit credit) {
        creditDebitRepository.save(credit);
    }
    public List<Credit> getAllCreditList() {
        return creditDebitRepository.findAll();
    }
    public long getCreditDebitById(long cid) {
        cid = creditDebitRepository.fingById(cid);
        return cid;
    }
```

5.CreditDebitController.java

```
package com.rajesh.controller;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.rajesh.model.Credit;
import com.rajesh.model.Debit;
import com.rajesh.model.User;
import com.rajesh.service.CreditDebitService;

@Controller
public class CreditDebitController {
    @Autowired
    CreditDebitService creditDebitService;

    @PostMapping("/user/savecreditdebit")
    public String saveCreditDebit(@RequestParam(value = "amount") String[] amount, 
            @RequestParam(value = "description") String[] description, 
            ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session,@ModelAttribute("command")Credit credit, BindingResult result) {
        try {
            List<Debit> debits = new ArrayList<Debit>(Arrays.asList());
            debits = credit.getDebit();
            for(int i=0; i<amount.length; i++) {
                Debit debit = new Debit();
                debit.setAmount(amount[i]);
                debit.setDescription(description[i]);
                debits.add(debit);
            }   
            System.out.println("debits ="+debits);
            List<Debit> debits1 = new ArrayList<Debit>();

            for(int i=0; i<debits.size(); i++)
            {
                debits1.add(new Debit(debits.get(i).getAmount(),debits.get(i).getDescription()));
            }
            System.out.println("debits1 ="+debits1);
            User user = new User();

             // Credit Data Set
                credit.setOpeningbalance(credit.getOpeningbalance());
                credit.setDate(credit.getDate());
                System.out.println("Date is: = "+credit.getDate());
                credit.setDebittotal(credit.getDebittotal());
                credit.setDrawertotal(credit.getDrawertotal());
                credit.setDebittotalplusdrawertotal(credit.getDebittotalplusdrawertotal());
                credit.setTodaybusiness(credit.getTodaybusiness());
                credit.setCreatedBy(user.getEmail());
                credit.setCreatedDate(new Date());
                credit.setUpdatedBy(user.getEmail());
                credit.setUpdatedDate(new Date());  
            //  Debit Data set  
                System.out.println("Debit List = " + debits1.size());
                System.out.println("Credit and Debit data seved successfully");
                credit.setDebit(debits1);
                creditDebitService.save(credit);
                model.put("success", "Data Saved Successfully");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "redirect:userdashboard";
    }
    @GetMapping("/user/getCreditDebit/{cid}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getCreditDebitById(@PathVariable("cid") long cid, @ModelAttribute("command") Credit credit, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request, BindingResult result) {
        creditDebitService.getCreditDebitById(cid);
        return "redirect:userdashboard";
    }
}
```

6.Error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'creditDebitController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'creditDebitService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'creditDebitService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'creditDebitRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'creditDebitRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract long com.rajesh.repository.CreditDebitRepository.fingById(long)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.rajesh.RojmatBootApplication.main(RojmatBootApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'creditDebitService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'creditDebitRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'creditDebitRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract long com.rajesh.repository.CreditDebitRepository.fingById(long)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'creditDebitRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract long com.rajesh.repository.CreditDebitRepository.fingById(long)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract long com.rajesh.repository.CreditDebitRepository.fingById(long)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:553) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:546) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:548) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [from com.rajesh.model.Credit c join credit_debit cd on(c.cid=cd.c_id) join com.rajesh.model.Debit d on(cd.d_id=d.did) WHERE c.cid=:cid]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:670) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 76 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [from com.rajesh.model.Credit c join credit_debit cd on(c.cid=cd.c_id) join com.rajesh.model.Debit d on(cd.d_id=d.did) WHERE c.cid=:cid]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:272) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 84 common frames omitted
```

Comment: JPA uses JPQL, not native SQL, in @Query.
`@Query(value= "from Credit c join credit_debit cd on(c.cid=cd.c_id) join Debit d on(cd.d_id=d.did) WHERE c.cid=:cid")
    long fingById(long cid);`
In the view of JPA, there is no relation like `credit_debit`.

Comment: how to do that can tell me please ? - Min Hyoung Hong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved by me. I will used findById(cid); they will  return particular id related data from thiese two table I has used JPA repository